Using OMI/Aura Ozone (O3) Total Column Daily L3 Global
I am quite new to GIS and I am not trained in this field. My current work interfered with GIS and I found myself at an impasse.
Does anybody know if the data from OMI/Aura Ozone (O3) Total Column Daily L3 Global can be expressed in latitude/longitude coordinates as opposed to SZA (Solar Zenith Angle) and VZA (Viewing Zenith Angle)?
If it cannot be expressed this way, is there an equivalent dataset to OMI/Aura Ozone that does give its data in latitude/longitude format?
As part of a larger study, I am trying to find a high-resolution dataset that gives ozone layer total column thickness for one specific day for various latitude/longitude coordinates. I am working with the OMI/Aura TOMS-Like Ozone and Radiative Cloud Fraction L3 1 day 0.25 degree x 0.25 degree V3 (OMTO3e) (https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/OMTO3e_003/summary) database. Studying the file structure with the following code
import h5py

filename_hdf = 'OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2023m0424_v003-2023m0426t030255.he5'

def h5_tree(val, pre=''):
    items = len(val)
    for key, val in val.items():
        items -= 1
        if items == 0:
            # the last item
            if type(val) == h5py._hl.group.Group:
                print(pre + '└── ' + key)
                h5_tree(val, pre+'    ')
            else:
                try:
                    print(pre + '└── ' + key + ' (%d)' % len(val))
                except TypeError:
                    print(pre + '└── ' + key + ' (scalar)')
        else:
            if type(val) == h5py._hl.group.Group:
                print(pre + '├── ' + key)
                h5_tree(val, pre+'│   ')
            else:
                try:
                    print(pre + '├── ' + key + ' (%d)' % len(val))
                except TypeError:
                    print(pre + '├── ' + key + ' (scalar)')

with h5py.File(filename_hdf, 'r') as hf:
    print(hf)
    h5_tree(hf)

I found that the Data fields were: ColumnAmmountO3, RadiativeCloudFraction, SolarZenithAngle, ViewingZenithAngle.
I do not know how to convert (SolarZenithAngle, ViewingZenithAngle) coordinates into (latitude, longitude) coordinates. I found a formula for VZA here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61261771/how-to-calculate-the-local-zenith-angle and I already knew the approximation formula for the SZA found in https://clima.github.io/Insolation.jl/dev/ZenithAngleEquations/ . But in order to do those conversions, I need to know the satellite subpoint latitude and longitude, which I do not know how to find.
How do I proceed from here?
Is there a way to find the satellite subpoint latitude and longitude, or is there some other algorithm which I am not aware of?

You don't convert SolarZenithAngle or ViewingZenithAngle into latitude, longitude coordinates. They are grids like ColumnAmountO3 and RadiativeCloudFraction and are already georeferenced.  However, your GIS software may not understand the georeferencing.
The coordinates of the four corners of the grid are in the hf['HDFEOS']['GRIDS']['OMI Column Amount O3'].attrs['GridSpan'] attribute and are simply -180,180,-90,90.
One way to get a GIS (like QGIS) to read the georeferenced data is to convert to a simple GeoTIFF format and specify the georeferencing and projection information using something like GDAL (using the gdal_translate commandline utility).
# Get a list of the subdatasets
gdalinfo OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2024m0101_v003-2024m0103t041643.he5

Driver: HDF5/Hierarchical Data Format Release 5
Files: OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2024m0101_v003-2024m0103t041643.he5
<snip...>
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=HDF5:"OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2024m0101_v003-2024m0103t041643.he5"://HDFEOS/GRIDS/OMI_Column_Amount_O3/Data_Fields/ColumnAmountO3
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[720x1440] //HDFEOS/GRIDS/OMI_Column_Amount_O3/Data_Fields/ColumnAmountO3 (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=HDF5:"OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2024m0101_v003-2024m0103t041643.he5"://HDFEOS/GRIDS/OMI_Column_Amount_O3/Data_Fields/RadiativeCloudFraction
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[720x1440] //HDFEOS/GRIDS/OMI_Column_Amount_O3/Data_Fields/RadiativeCloudFraction (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=HDF5:"OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2024m0101_v003-2024m0103t041643.he5"://HDFEOS/GRIDS/OMI_Column_Amount_O3/Data_Fields/SolarZenithAngle
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[720x1440] //HDFEOS/GRIDS/OMI_Column_Amount_O3/Data_Fields/SolarZenithAngle (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_4_NAME=HDF5:"OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2024m0101_v003-2024m0103t041643.he5"://HDFEOS/GRIDS/OMI_Column_Amount_O3/Data_Fields/ViewingZenithAngle
  SUBDATASET_4_DESC=[720x1440] //HDFEOS/GRIDS/OMI_Column_Amount_O3/Data_Fields/ViewingZenithAngle (32-bit floating-point)

# Show details of the subdataset of interest. Just for info, you don't need to do this.
gdalinfo HDF5:"OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2024m0101_v003-2024m0103t041643.he5"://HDFEOS/GRIDS/OMI_Column_Amount_O3/Data_Fields/ColumnAmountO3

Driver: HDF5Image/HDF5 Dataset
Files: OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2024m0101_v003-2024m0103t041643.he5
Size is 1440, 720
Metadata:
  <snip...>
  HDFEOS_GRIDS_OMI_Column_Amount_O3_GCTPProjectionCode=0 
  HDFEOS_GRIDS_OMI_Column_Amount_O3_GridOrigin=Center
  HDFEOS_GRIDS_OMI_Column_Amount_O3_GridSpacing=(0.25,0.25)
  HDFEOS_GRIDS_OMI_Column_Amount_O3_GridSpacingUnit=deg
  HDFEOS_GRIDS_OMI_Column_Amount_O3_GridSpan=(-180,180,-90,90)
  HDFEOS_GRIDS_OMI_Column_Amount_O3_GridSpanUnit=deg
  HDFEOS_GRIDS_OMI_Column_Amount_O3_NumberOfLatitudesInGrid=720 
  HDFEOS_GRIDS_OMI_Column_Amount_O3_NumberOfLongitudesInGrid=1440 
  HDFEOS_GRIDS_OMI_Column_Amount_O3_Projection=Geographic
  HDFEOS_INFORMATION_HDFEOSVersion=HDFEOS_5.1.16
  <snip...>

#Convert to a georeferenced GeoTIFF
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr -180 -90 180 90 HDF5:"OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2024m0101_v003-2024m0103t041643.he5"://HDFEOS/GRIDS/OMI_Column_Amount_O3/Data_Fields/ColumnAmountO3 OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2024m0101_v003-2024m0103t041643-03.tif

Displayed in QGIS:

